# Zune software not recognizing attached WP7

Tags: windows-phone, zune-software

When Zune software is already started and I attach my phone, Zune never recognizes that I've attached it. However, when I close Zune software and attach my phone, it launches Zune automatically and it does recognize the attached phone. What can I do to have the already started Zune software recognize the phone?

My phone is an HTC Pro 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done the 
[Windows Phone Registry Hack](http://timoboehme.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/windows-phone-7-hack/) this situation can occur. Also if your Firmware is not fully up to date.

**Be sure that you are logged in (On top, right of Zune) with your LiveID**

**Please update to the latest Zune Software (4.8.2345.0)**

**Please update to the latest WP7 OS Version (7.10.7740.16) Mango**

**Try to fix your USB registry**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925196

If it still does NOT recognize the device. You can uninstall Zune using "remove program" under default windows system menu. Then Install again [www.zune.net](http://www.zune.net)

Comment: None of these helped.

Comment: ok, I've updated the ideas with a 3rd item which worked on a Kindle-USB problem. Just run the "FixIt" download.

Comment: Just wanted to verify that you understand my question as posed. Zune does recognize the phone when attaching the phone launches Zune. It does not recognize the phone when I attach it while Zune is already running.

Comment: Ok. But did you hack the registry? Because it sounds like you did: http://timoboehme.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/windows-phone-7-hack/

Comment: Nope, did not do this.

Comment: Hi Mike. I always fixed all problems by using the stuff above? In this case I ask: did you do the last fix? If you plug in the WP7, does the device manager recognize the device correctly? Do you have any other devices connected? Did you ever had any other WP7 connected? Do you use default WP7 or special unlocked version?

Comment: I had this problem before I activated my Live ID on my WP7, could it be the same you are experiencing?

Comment: Well idea Krimson! @Mike C. have you waited 10 seconds in Zune and then do you see your LiveID Account name on the top right of Zune there? Also you can checkout while going to "Settings" > "Account" and see your Zune-Tag!